# React-native with Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react-native

I'm totally newbie in `React_Native` and trying to learn more about it. I tried this [tutorial](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/november/getting-started-with-react-native-android-and-couchbase-lite) to learn how to work with Studio and `React-Native`. But still I'm not getting it. How to code in studio and link it with `js`. Did any body have any idea how to do it or tutorial links or references.

Comment: When you write the code in js, and run. The react creates some folders in the project path, one of them is  `android`, this is a fully working `andriod` project. You can import this folder in `Andriod Studio` and work with it as an native `andriod` app. The `js` files, although you can work with them in `Andriod Studio` but you may prefer to use some specific `js` editor

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial seems to be pretty clear actually.
What do you mean by

> But still I'm not getting it. How to code in studio and link it with
>   js

If you are talking about the way you link the JS, it is done through an activity, calling your js file.
If you are asking where to put your JS files, the tutorial tells you to put them in your root, but you are free to do it in other way.
If you ask how to edit your code through Android Studio, you can open the js file as any other file in order to code inside it.

It is possible that my answer is not what you expected, in this case, try to be more precise about what you want us to explain to you, I did not really get it.

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully installed what you need to start developing you can try the tutorial from the [React Native docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html)

In case you haven't finished the setup yet you can go through the installation on [Getting Started](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) or start developing with the web application in the tutorial, you just need your browser. Then later you can produce an Android app with the code from that tutorial.